# How to install SVN client version 1.8 on CentOS/RHEL 6?

Tags: svn, centos6, rhel6

I'm trying to install the SVN client version 1.8 on CentOS 6. I'm using the description on

http://tecadmin.net/install-subversion-1-8-on-centos-rhel/

All activities are running successful without any problems. But after that I get

```
/> svn --version
svn, Version 1.6.11 (r934486)
...
...
...
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The steps decribed on the following site works for me:

[http://snowdream.github.io/blog/centos/2013/11/08/how-to-install-subversion-18-on-centos-64/](https://web.archive.org/web/20140118000705/http://snowdream.github.io/blog/centos/2013/11/08/how-to-install-subversion-18-on-centos-64/)

From the article:

> ## How to install subversion 1.8 on CentOS 6.4
>
> If you get the error like "This client is too old to work with working copy" when you use svn client, it means you need a newer svn client.
>   Let us update the svn client on CentOS 6.4 now.
>
> 1. Remove the old version subversion
>
>    ```
>    yum remove subversion
>    ```
> 2. Download and install subversion 1.8.4-2
>
>    ```
>    mkdir download && cd download
>
>    wget -c http://opensource.wandisco.com/centos/6/svn-1.8/RPMS/i686/mod_dav_svn-1.8.4-2.i686.rpm
>    wget -c http://opensource.wandisco.com/centos/6/svn-1.8/RPMS/i686/serf-1.3.2-2.i686.rpm
>    wget -c http://opensource.wandisco.com/centos/6/svn-1.8/RPMS/i686/subversion-1.8.4-2.i686.rpm
>    wget -c http://opensource.wandisco.com/centos/6/svn-1.8/RPMS/i686/subversion-gnome-1.8.4-2.i686.rpm
>    wget -c http://opensource.wandisco.com/centos/6/svn-1.8/RPMS/i686/subversion-javahl-1.8.4-2.i686.rpm
>    wget -c http://opensource.wandisco.com/centos/6/svn-1.8/RPMS/i686/subversion-perl-1.8.4-2.i686.rpm
>    wget -c http://opensource.wandisco.com/centos/6/svn-1.8/RPMS/i686/subversion-python-1.8.4-2.i686.rpm
>    wget -c http://opensource.wandisco.com/centos/6/svn-1.8/RPMS/i686/subversion-tools-1.8.4-2.i686.rpm
>
>    sudo rpm -ivh *.rpm
>    ```
> 3. Check
>
>    ```
>    svn --version
>    ```
>
> If the subversion is successfully installed,you can see the following:
>
> ```
> svn, version 1.8.4 (r1534716)
>   compiled Nov  1 2013, 15:45:40 on i686-pc-linux-gnu
>
> Copyright (C) 2013 The Apache Software Foundation.
> This software consists of contributions made by many people;
> see the NOTICE file for more information.
> Subversion is open source software, see http://subversion.apache.org/
> ```

Comment: The sense is that links can and do frequently go dead whilst an answer will be here until there is no more SE. People also change links too http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/141203/blogs-sun-com-is-dead

Answer (score -1):

Try to download the binaries directly:
http://www.wandisco.com/subversion/download/download-certified-wandisco-subversion-binaries?f=subversion/subversion_installer_1.8.sh

the link shows you a window form to fill in, and after you can proceed with download

this is just an example, the file you download it is the 1.8.10 version...

```
# chmod +x svn1.7_centos6_wandisco.sh
# ./svn1.7_centos6_wandisco.sh
# yum upgrade
```

As written in the instruction this install only the client.

I hope this can help you.

Comment: Your link is invalid. May be you mean the shell script which I can also download on the site http://svn-ref.assembla.com/download-clients.html . Also this are excuting without any problems. But after that I will have svn V1.6 ... :-( . But the description I have post in my answer works for me

Answer (score -1):

first check the svn version and  location :

command 
1. svn --version
 o/p:
 svn, version 1.8.16 (r1740329)
   compiled Jul  8 2016, 13:43:28 on x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu

2. type -a svn
   svn is /usr/local/bin/svn
   svn is /usr/bin/svn
   svn is /usr/bin/X11/svn

please remove /usr/local/bin/svn

sudo rm /usr/local/bin/svn

Comment: These steps detail removal of SVN, not installation as per the question. What you have detailed is a messy removal, at that.